# How to boot from USB and copy files to USB?

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, usb

My Windows 7 installation is broken. It won't boot and when I run the installation from bootable USB, it gets stuck right at the beginning saying "Loading something something (can't remember what)", no matter what option I choose.

Now, I want to just copy a few files on a USB drive. How would I go about doing that? I have "Universal USB Installer" but:

1. Which Linux to choose? I don't actually care which OS it runs.
2. Will it allow me to copy files to the USB even though I am booting from it?
3. Any other software to use instead to get this (I assume very simple) task done?

Thank you!

Comment: Follow instructions to create a bootable Ubuntu USB. This will allow you to read NTFS. You would need to download the Linux ISO before using the USB creator applications...

Comment: @BigChris Right. But when in Ubuntu (running from USB), how can I access the USB drive?

Comment: You should be able to write to the disk as normal. Create a folder on the disk to store your rescued files. Job done.